# Overriding maven dependency with child dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I would like to upgrade version of *spring-boot-starter-logging*, but I am facing the problem with overriding maven dependency.

Dependency tree before any changes:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
```

By modifying parent pom and overriding dependency in dependencyManagement block:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I am able to override "sole dependency" - only *spring-boot-starter-logging* version is updated, but child dependencies (logback-classic and log4j-to-slf4j) exists still in old versions:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
```

Is it possible to upgrade child dependency versions by overriding version of *spring-boot-starter-logging* so that new versions of child dependencies will be taken from *spring-boot-starter-logging* pom?

I know that I can override all the child versions one by one in dependencyManagement block, but I would like to know if there is another possibility.

Comment: Have you tried just an explicit dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.2:compile` in your pom?

Comment: Then I will have to change it in each project that uses ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.2:compile``` and I want to avoid that. I would like to make as small change as possible.